# How can I deploy new version of Blazor Server app without interrupting existing user sessions?

Tags: deployment, blazor, blazor-server-side, high-availability, .net-6.0

I have a Blazor (server hosting model) app written in .NET 6 hosted on an on-premise VM Windows Server VM with IIS.

I already have 3 stages (test, staging, production), each as IIS WebSite with it's own application pool.

How can I deploy new version of my app without loosing in-memory state in existing blazor sessions (not HTTP Session).

Comment: You can't because the SignalR connection will be closed.
The only way to do this is to have one auth server+ two production server. New users that authenticate will be redirected to the new production version. When everyone is disconnected from the old production server you update it.

Comment: SignalR connection would recover, the problem is that the inmemory state would be lost, so I will need the old and new app running side by side and some kind of load balancer.

Comment: What you can also do is to connect to a SignalR hub and handle the message "Navigate to a new server"

Comment: I'm interested in a solution as well. I think there are two ways to approach this: migrate existing sessions to the new application, or keep the old application running to handle any existing connections and serve new connections from the new application. The latter is what typically happens in a normal request-response deployment, however the lifetime of the sessions is someting to address: "Server shutting down in 10 minutes, reconnect to avoid interruption".

Comment: Did you ever find a good way to implement this?

Comment: I'm also looking for a way to do this if anyone has found a setup that works